# WPF grand parent of context menu option

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I am dynamically creating a ContextMenu which contains a ComboxBox as one of the items and it is used by two separate Canvas. The combobox comtains percentage values so the idea is to rightclick on one of the canvas, select the percentage and set the RenderTransform. However, I'm unable to determine on whcih canvas the contextmenu was opened. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ContextMenu`'s [`PlacementTarget` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)